# as-pect.config.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module"

Tags: node.js, webassembly, nearprotocol, aspect, near

When I test with as-pect I get an error in CRUD dApp with NEAR. The whole error I get is as follows;

```
yarn test
```

> [Error] There was a problem loading [/Users/malibilgin/Documents/Web3/order-management-with-near/contract/as-pect.config.js].
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/malibilgin/Documents/Web3/order-management-with-near/contract/as-pect.config.js from /Users/malibilgin/Documents/Web3/order-management-with-near/contract/node_modules/asbuild/node_modules/@as-pect/cli/lib/run.js not supported.
> as-pect.config.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
> Instead rename as-pect.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /Users/malibilgin/Documents/Web3/order-management-with-near/contract/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
> at run (/Users/malibilgin/Documents/Web3/order-management-with-near/contract/node_modules/asbuild/node_modules/@as-pect/cli/lib/run.js:182:25)
> at Object.asp (/Users/malibilgin/Documents/Web3/order-management-with-near/contract/node_modules/asbuild/node_modules/@as-pect/cli/lib/index.js:64:9)
> at Object. (/Users/malibilgin/Documents/Web3/order-management-with-near/contract/node_modules/asbuild/node_modules/@as-pect/cli/lib/test.js:2:28) {
> code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
> }
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

but when I clone from the address

> https://github.com/near-examples/crud-tutorial.git

and test it, the test found here works successfully. I couldn't understand where I missed it. The project I made is similar to this clone.

my package.json;

```
{
"name": "contract",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "module",
"exports": {
    ".": {
        "import": "./build/release.js",
        "types": "./build/release.d.ts"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "asbuild:debug": "asc assembly/index.ts --target debug",
    "asbuild:release": "asc assembly/index.ts --target release",
    "start": "npx serve .",
    "build": "asb",
    "deploy": "near dev-deploy build/release/contract.wasm",
    "dev": "npm run build && npm run deploy",
    "test": "asp",
    "asbuild:untouched": "asc assembly/index.ts --target debug",
    "asbuild:optimized": "asc assembly/index.ts --target release",
    "asbuild": "npm run asbuild:untouched && npm run asbuild:optimized"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "assemblyscript": "^0.19.14"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@assemblyscript/loader": "^0.19.14",
    "asbuild": "^0.2.0",
    "assemblyscript": "^0.19.14",
    "near-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "near-sdk-as": "^3.2.3"
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

After struggling for 1 day and asking my question here, I was able to solve my problem about 10 minutes later. all I had to do was delete this in my package.json

```
"type": "module"
```

Comment: and I had to add it because of another error :(

Comment: module is used to be able to make use of IMPORT.
This preferably when the script is modular and is used by other files or in the case of libraries. Removing them is not, however, a solution. A stacker must be used.

Comment: @Jasp402 thanks. It was a problem I encountered during the learning phase, and this is how I got rid of this error.